# friend template definition. Include <T> when and where?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, friend

I think I just need another set of eyes to find out what I'm doing wrong.

This is the error:

```
bfgs_template.hpp:478:5: error: ‘di’ was not declared in this scope
bfgs_template.hpp:478:8: error: ‘b’ was not declared in this scope
```

and this is a snapshot of the code:

```
template<typename T>
void update_d();

template<typename T>
class BFGSB: public BFGS<T>{
protected:
  double *di;
  int b;
public:
  friend void update_d<T>();
};


template<typename T>
void update_d(){
    di[b] = 0.0; 
}
```

Btw.  While I didn't post the rest of the code.  di is initialized and if I make update_d a member of the class.  Everything runs smooth.

Comment: What kind of magic are you expecting the `friend` declaration to work? Pass a reference to an instance of `BFGSB` to `update_d` and it'll be able to operate on the private members of that instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because `update_d` is a friend of `BFGSB`, it doesn't mean it can just access `di` and `b`. It's a non-member function just like any other. It isn't associated with any particular instance of `BFGSB` and so there are no particular `di` or `b` objects to access. Making it a friend simply means that it is *allowed* to access the `di` and `b` members of a `BFGSB` object. For example, it could do this:

```
template<typename T>
void update_d(){
    BFGSB<T> obj; // We can access the privates of this object
    obj.di[obj.b] = 0.0; 
}
```